# Weird behaviour with <c-i> and :normal

Tags: normal-mode, jumplist

- When I execute:

  ```
  :exe "normal! \<c-o>"
  ```

  , it works as expected (it jumps to the previous cursor location).
- But when I execute:

  ```
  :exe "normal! \<c-i>"
  ```

  , it outputs the `E471` error:

  > E471: Argument required

  Then I need to prepend with `1` to make it work:

  ```
  :exe "normal! 1\<c-i>"
  ```

Is it a normal behaviour?

Please note I'm using vim-gtk (graphical).

Vim version : 7.4
Rustines : 1-1689

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes I think it's a normal behavior.

In `:help keycode`, you can read that `<C-I>` and `<Tab>` have the same decimal keycode (`9`):

```
<Tab>       tab         CTRL-I    9 *tab* *Tab*
```

Which means that Vim and gVim can't make the difference between the two keys.
You can find a technical reason for this [here](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-map-tab-and-c-i-independently-tp1185417p1185428.html).

So `"\<C-I>"` is translated into a literal tab character.
After the translation, Vim probably parses the tab as a syntax character separating a command from its arguments (here `:normal` from `{commands}`) ; like a space.
Since there's nothing after your tab, Vim doesn't pass anything to `:normal`, and the latter complains with the error `E471: Argument required`.

The solution is given in `:help :normal`:

```
    {commands} cannot start with a space.  Put a count of
    1 (one) before it, "1 " is one space.
```

You have to prefix the `{commands}` with `1` when they begin with a space (and probably with a tab).

Hitting <kbd>1</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> in normal mode has the same effect as hitting <kbd>Ctrl-I</kbd> alone.
But here on the command-line, by prefixing `<C-I>` with a count, you prevent Vim from parsing it as a syntax character, but rather as a part of the argument `{commands}`.

Comment: It looks a real good answer; I will look at it a bit before accepting it